# Converting pk to slug with Django-Generic-Detail view

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I have gotten my test site up successfully and am now trying to change the url link from a private key to a slug to make the link more intuitive for the user. I have read many questions, but have not found one that adequately answers my question.

I understand I use the exmodel.name instead of the .slug (code below); however the exmodel.slug does not return anything and the database record is one word so it shouldn't matter (figured I would tackle one problem at a time). The exmodel_list.html compiles as expected, but the exmodel_detail.html returns a 404 error. This doesn't make sense to me since it works when I use the  method. Any insight or articles you could provide would be much appreciated. Thanks for the help!

## models.py

```
class ExModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter name of example model')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(ExModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this model."""
        return reverse('exmodel-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

## views.py

```
class ExModelListView(generic.ListView):
    model = ExModel

class ExModelDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = ExModel
```

## urls.py

```
app_name = 'presentInfo'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('exmodel-test', views.ExModelListView.as_view(), name='exmodel'),
    path('exmodel-test/<slug:slug>/', views.ExModelDetailView.as_view(), name='exmodel-detail'),
]
```

## exmodel_list.html template

```
{% if exmodel_list %}
<ul>
    {% for exmodel in exmodel_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'presentInfo:exmodel-detail' exmodel.name %}">{{ exmodel.name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %} <ul><li><a href="">no models</a></li></ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does you error is something like this No ex model found matching the query.

Comment: Yes, precisely. I didn't notice that message before. I guess that's another path I can start researching. Thanks!!

Comment: Then most probably.  Yo do not have the ExModel Object in database.
For eg. if you are looking for /exmodel-test/tes1/  and got error. There is no such object with slug OR name test1.

Comment: Ok, but that's where I'm a bit confused--I do have an object (2 actually) in the database. The site compiles as expected when using the private key method; but when I attempt to use the slug method, it throws the 404 error. As I mentioned, although I am unable to get the exmodel.slug working properly, this shouldn't be the issue because I have verified the exmodel.name does return something.

Comment: I believe I have figured out part of the problem: the save function is not saving as I expected. I incorrectly assumed I could ignore this error by calling exmodel.name. However, I have still been unable to save properly. I have looked at [1] and [2] and have replicated their code, but have yet to be successful.  
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780538/why-is-my-overridden-save-method-not-running-in-my-django-model  
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176569/slugfield-in-django-and-overriding-save

Comment: Please post your full trace of error and also detail.html